# Async queue on music discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, queue, youtube-dl

So I'm making a music bot for my server that uses discord.py. it works, but when I add a playlist, it waits a very long process to start to play.
It looks like that the process to put the track information on the async.Queue, is blocking to get from the same queue...
Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

In this method, it waits to get a track in async.Queue (which is the queue of the player), and play the track.

```
class VoiceState:
    async def audio_player_task(self):
        while True:
            self.next.clear()
            self.now = None

            if not (self.loop or self.repeat):
                # Try to get the next song within 3 minutes.
                # If no song will be added to the queue in time,
                # the player will disconnect due to performance
                # reasons.
                try:
                    async with timeout(180):  # 3 minutes
                        self.current = await self.songs.get()
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    self.bot.loop.create_task(self.stop())
                    self.audio_player = self.bot.loop.create_task(
                        self.audio_player_task()
                    )
                    return

                self.current.source.volume = self._volume
                self.voice.play(self.current.source, after=self.play_next_song)
                await self.current.source.channel.send(
                    embed=self.current.create_embed()
                )
            await self.next.wait()
```

And here, it defines the voice_state

```
    def get_voice_state(self, ctx: commands.Context):
       state = self.voice_states.get(ctx.guild.id)
        if not state:
            state = VoiceState(self.bot, ctx)
            self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id] = state

        return state

    async def cog_before_invoke(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        ctx.voice_state = self.get_voice_state(ctx)
```

Here is the command play. It puts the track in the async.queue. When is a playlist, it iterates in a loop and add all the tracks from the playlist.

```
    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p"])
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, search: str):
        if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
            await ctx.invoke(self._join)

        if search.__contains__("?list="):
            await self._playlist(ctx, search)

        else:
            async with ctx.typing():
                source = await YTDLSource.create_source(
                    ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop
                )
                song = Song(source)
                await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
                await ctx.send("キューに追加されました {}".format(str(source)))


    async def _playlist(self, ctx: commands.Context, search: str):
        ydl_opts = {"ignoreerrors": True, "quit": True}

        with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            playlist_dict = ydl.extract_info(search, download=False)
            playlistTitle = playlist_dict["title"]
            playlist = dict()

            for video in playlist_dict["entries"]:
                for prop in ["id", "title"]:
                    print(prop, "--", video.get(prop))
                    playlist[
                        video.get("title")
                    ] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video.get("id")

        for _title, _link in playlist.items():
            source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, _link, loop=self.bot.loop)
            song = Song(source)
            await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song)
        await ctx.send(f"**{playlistTitle}からの曲を`{playlist.__len__()}`件キューに追加されました**")
```

I tried several things like using thread to run self._playlist method, or asyncio.create_task(self._playlist(ctx, search))... but it does not worked.

The fun thing is when i try to use await asyncio.sleep() inside the for looping in _playlist, it doesnt work.

im expecting that when i add a playlist, it gets the track from the queue and play it in the moment when the first track is inserted on it, not when all the playlist process is over.